# How to classify/organize BPMN process definitions in Camunda

Tags: camunda, bpmn

I'm currently working on a Camunda 7.16 instance and I'm deploying some BPMN processes.

I know that all processes are saved as resources and can be retrieved using the process-definition GET REST call.

I would like to know if there is a way to logically organize them, I mean which would be the better way to tell a process apart from another, like it happens in Document Management Systems where every object can be classified assigning a particular document class.

I searched a lot on the documentation but it seems that the deployed processes are flat saved and can be filtered by some system properties. When they become numerous it would be difficult to tell them apart.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not as sophisticated as you are envisioning it, but you can use deployments to bundle multiple bpmn, dmn and other resources.
You can do so via processes.xml, via [REST API](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/reference/rest/deployment/post-deployment/) or when uploading multiple files via the modeler in one deployment.

To filter process definition, you can use the REST API: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/reference/rest/process-definition/get-query/. For instance you can filter by process definition name or key, deploymentId, resourceId, versionTag, etc.
Filtering can use exact match or *like*.

Depending on what subset you are looking for you would need naming convention on one of those attributes. For instance the version tag could include information suitable for your classification.

(The category attribute looks promising at first, but is not a custom filed, but the kind of model, e.g. http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL).

Comment: Thank for your reply, but the main problem is that once I uploaded the process definitions I can't filter them.
I'm looking for a way to organize them so they can be somehow filtered when calling the process-definitons REST API

Comment: updated answer with filter info